# Cannot compile an OS for ARM on OSX

Tags: linux, macos, arm, ubuntu-14.04

Github page for the OS is here: https://github.com/rellermeyer/course_os

From the wiki in the Github page, it indicates me to install glib and texinfo. It also indicates me how to build the toolchain.

On my first attempt at building, it told me I needed wget and I installed using HomeBrew. When issuing the command $ brew list, I get:

```
$ brew list
cloog018    glib        make        postgresql  wget
coreutils   gmp4        mpfr2       python
gcc48       isl011      openssl     readline
gdbm        libffi      ossp-uuid   sqlite
gettext     libmpc08    pkg-config  texinfo
```

Which shows me I have everything I need. However, on the second attempt it gives me an error:

```
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: invalid host type: Systems/course_os/toolchain/arm-none-eabi
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `Systems/course_os/toolchain/arm-none-eabi': machine `Systems/course_os/toolchain/arm-none' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh ../../src/gcc-4.8.1/config.sub Systems/course_os/toolchain/arm-none-eabi failed
```

I don't understand the warning and what it is it's missing. Additionally, when I try to do the same steps with Ubuntu, it runs perfectly and I'm able to go on to building the kernel and run Hello World. What does Ubuntu have that OSX doesn't that makes the OS run? Could it be an issue with gcc?

Note: I'm running OSX Yosemite 10.10 and Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Basically you have a choice to make - if you want to work on the project, setup a VM and use the Linux configuration that already works.  If you prefer to work on the build system before you even start on the project, then set about understanding why that isn't working on OSX.  Do you have the arm gcc version it wants installed?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my problem. There was an issue with one of my target folders being two words. I changed it from Operating System to OS and it ran perfectly. Thanks!